# Grammaticality of the given sentence

Tags: grammaticality

**I was surprised myself at how good I nailed the interview.**

So here the speaker is trying to convey that they were surprised at how well the interview went and how well they, the speaker, performed. But would this sentence be considered grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2):

While **good** is often used in the sense of **well**, as in:

> We are all good; thanks for asking.

It doesn't work in your sentence; you need to use **well** - and the use of **myself**, while legitimate for emphasis, is unnecessary.

Moreover, to **nail something** in the sense of **achieving/accomplishing it** is slang. So it's fine in certain contexts and dubious in others. In short, you might rephrase as:

> I was surprised (myself) at how **well** I nailed the interview
> or, more formally:
> I was surprised (myself) at how well I did/succeeded in the interview.

https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Nailed%20it
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nailed

Comment: Or more naturally, *I surprised myself by how well I did* or *I was surprised by how well I did.* I don't think *at* is the most common preposition here.

Comment: @JasonBassford Much better!

Comment: But does using BY instead of AT make a difference here in terms of meaning?